# Birt dynamic image uri

Tags: eclipse-plugin, birt

I have the URI to an image stored in a database. I created a dataset, which contains the image location. When choosing the location of the image I used a script which says this.uri = row[location],
however the image is not rendering and I am getting an error which says the rsource could not be reached. Is what I am trying to do possible in Birt, or is there any way to dynamically set the uri?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there a reason the image needs to live on the database? If not it would be easier to work with in BIRT if you made it a library item.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to use a script to do this.

I assume this image is embedded within a table bound to the dataset. If it is not, you just have to select the dataset in the "bindings" tab of the image.  When the image is correctly bound we have to:

Select the image -> properties -> reference -> edit

Set the option "select from URI", and for "Enter URI" expression don't forget to switch from "constant" to "javascript syntax".

With the expression builder select your dataset column within "Available column bindings" and here we go!

If you still have an issue check the URI generated with your web browser console.